# Nvidia GT 540M on ASUS working on Ubuntu 11.10 optimus 100%

Tags: 11.10, nvidia-optimus, asus

This is a laptop ASUS K53SV-SX538V  with Nvidia Geforce GT 540M.

I have several questions about this topic:
1. Do I need to install additional drivers other than the one Ubuntu recommends during installation?
2. If so, after installing bumblebee or ironhide in Ubuntu, how I can set any program to always start with Nvidia and Intel?
3. As seen in some forums, how can I disable the Nvidia card?
4. How do people run Ubuntu if it's always throttled to 100%? I can not run 1080p movies automatically or run games, etc.

Regards, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:
1. DON'T! If you do, you'll break the xorg and you'll have to revert to the original xorg.conf....

1. I've tried to get bumblebee/ironhide working on Asus U41SV with the same graphic card as yours and so far I've been unsucessfull :( 
   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657660
2. I've used a script to turn on/off the nvidia card, but I can't find it now... I'll recheck later!
3. At this moment, I am patiently waiting for better news from the optimus technologies.... :(

FYI, I know that in the ubuntu forums there is a "how to" on asus laptops, but, again, can't find it now...

cheers mate
Rita

Answer (score -1):

1. Restricted drivers (aka nvidia proprietary ones)
2. That's only for the open source drivers, don't use them imho.
3. Install the proprietary drivers first ;)
4. It's throttled since without proper video driver support (as in nouveau instead of the proprietary nvidia) it doesn't always use the video card to help with the decoding (also you may just be on the default intel one :P ).

Comment: 1. [Won't work for Optimus laptops](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969) 2 is wrong, Bumblebee works with either nouveau and nvidia. 3. No, it will not disable the card, but increase power usage.